# Why dd seems to provide corrupt copies?

Tags: dd, usb-drive, iso, bootable

Tried this with different machines running Centos and Ubuntu, with different USB flash drives but dd keeps producing unbootable flash drives.

```
$ sudo dd if=foo.iso of=/dev/sdb bs=1M status=progress && sync
548****** bytes (548 MB, 523 MiB) copied, 7 s, 78.3 MB/s
551+1 records in
551+1 records out
577****** bytes (578 MB, 551 MiB) copied, 8.70126 s, 66.4 MB/s
$ sudo md5sum /dev/sdb
****************************ef59  /dev/sdb
$ sudo md5sum foo.iso
****************************21ce  foo.iso
```

MD5 sums are different.

The result of
sudo dd if=/dev/sdb of=bar.iso bs=1M status=progress && sync
is totally different in byte-to-byte compare tool to foo.iso either.

And another thing, the resulting flash drive does not read well when mounted.

Why and how to fix that?

Comment: /dev/sdb is larger than the iso and the data that is not part of the filesystem still counts to the md5sum.

Answer (score 3):

Your `/dev/sdb` probably holds more data than the exact size of `foo.iso`.
A disk drive can't be truncated to length, so `dd` just copies the data it has to copy, and leaves the rest in place. When `md5sum` reads it, it also reads the trailing part. Even if the tail is just zeroes, it still changes the hash.

You'd need to check the length of `foo.iso`, and then take the hash of just the initial part.

E.g. on a GNU system:

```
len=$(stat -c %s foo.iso)
sudo head -c "$len" /dev/sdb | md5sum
```

(Or check the output of `ls -l` to get the file length.)

Comment: Tried as you advised. The hashes are still not the same.